# How would I optimize this method for point of circle collision detection?

Tags: python, python-3.x, collision

I am working on a python method with is supposed to return the coordinates of interception (the point of collision) for two touching circles. The method works as expected but it seems to be overtly expensive for its purpose.

There should only ever be one point of interception and the sizes of these circles can vary.

```
def getPointOfContact(self, body):
    a1 = min(self.pos.x, body.pos.x) # The x value of the centre of the left-most circle
    b1 = min(self.pos.y, body.pos.y) # The y value of the up-most circle
    a2 = max(self.pos.x, body.pos.x) # The x value of the right-most circle
    b2 = max(self.pos.y, body.pos.y) # The y value of the down-most circle
    dx = a2-a1 # (Delta x) The difference in x positions
    dy = b2-b1 # (Delta y) The difference in y positions
    if dy == 0: # In case of no difference in y,
        m = 0 # Gradient is "zero"
    elif dx == 0: # In case of no difference in x,
        m = float("inf") # Gradient is "infinity"
    else:
        m = dy/dx # Gradient
    if a1 == self.pos.x: # Such that left-most circle's radius is used
        r1 = (self.size.x)/2
    else:
        r1 = (body.size.x)/2
    # Calculates the x position of intersection using trig
    x = a1+(r1*math.cos(math.atan(m))) 
    if b1 == self.pos.y: # Such that up-most circle's radius is used
        r1 = (self.size.x)/2
    else:
        r1 = (body.size.x)/2
    # Calculates the y position of intersection using trig
    y = b1+(r1*math.sin(math.atan(m)))
    return (int(x), int(y)) # Returns the coordinates as a tuple of integers
```

The actual calculation is actually fairly straight forward. It simply adds the x and y components of the radii displacement to the coordinate of the centre of the circle.

The problem is that a lot has to be in place in order from the calculation to be valid, ie the circle used must have the smallest component and the radius (r1) much match to the circle.

Would there be a way of simplifying the method, or even less expensive technique altogether?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps the best place to as is in [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: If the code works as intended and you'd like a review of your code, yes this would be a good question for Code Review. You are welcome to post your question there, if you do so it is best to delete this one so we don't have duplicates.

Comment: @Phrancis, would there be a way of moving it there without deleting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I get it. You have the radius of the first circle and you assume they are exactly tangent, right? Then just get rid of your `cos`, `sin` and `atan`:

```
d = sqrt(d1**2 + d2**2)
x = a1 + dx * r1 / d
y = b1 + dy * r1 / d
```

Look at this triangle where the `+` are the centers and `*` the intersection:

```
  0<-dx->|      
0 +
^  \ r1
|   \
|    *   d = r1+r2 = sqrt(dx**2 + dy**2)
dy    \ 
|      \ r2
v       \
-        +
```

Note 1: if `m=dy/dx` and you try to compute `atan(m)` then you'd better udirectly use [`atan2(dy, dx)`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/math.html#math.atan2) which will take care of the annoying zeroes and infinity.

Note 2: `cos(atan(dy/dx))==dx/R` with `R=sqrt(dx**2+dy**2)` and same with `sin` and `dy` since `atan(dy/dx)` is the angle such that `dx = R*cos(theta)` and `dy = R*sin(theta)`.

Note 3: you're casting things into `int` so your circles and intersections might be a bit off.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. The use of the distance between the centers of the circles worked well, as did the alteration of atan2(y, x). I don't understand what you mean with your note 2. Could you reiterate?

Comment: Ahh! Your ASCII drawing of the triangle really explains how it all works. I will probably use r1+r2 as r2 is also known, just excluded for simplicity. Thanks for all the help!